# Optimizing JS code

Tags: javascript

I have two variables that could be the same. In such a case I am assigning one of them to be `undefined`. Is this code the best way I can write it?

```
    let folderOwner = $("#change-folder-owner").val();
    let folderUser = $("#user_name_alias").data('value');

    folderOwner = (folderOwner === folderUser) ? undefined : folderOwner;
```

Can someone please help me with a better way?

Comment: Why should the value be undefined if they are equal?

Comment: Using `if` can be clearer and easier to understand than the ternary operator

Comment: @dustytrash I need to use that undefined elsewhere

Answer (score 4):

It would be clearer to use `if`:

```
if (folderOwner === folderUser) folderOwner = undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid re-assigning `folderOwner`'s value. Use two separate variables for the raw values, then evaluate for `folderOwner`'s value.

```
const ownerValue = ...

const userValue = ...

const folderOwner = (ownerValue === userValue) ? undefined : ownerValue
```